# Regex returns no results

Tags: python, regex

I've written a regular expression that can extract a period of years from a unicode string (for eg. `2014-2015`). The `\d{1,2}\^` in the regex represents month code, which may or may not exist.

Anyway, here is the code I have written:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
list_elem = '''Frank P. Smith (1886–1888)
Edgar Grant Sisson (1914–1917)
Douglas Z. Doty (1917–1918)
 {{Ray Long}} (1918–1931)

Harry Payne Burton (1931–1942)
Frances Whiting (1942–1945)
Arthur Gordon (1946–1948)'''

period_regex = ur'(\d{1,2}\^)?\s?\d{4}\s?(–|-)\s?(\d{1,2}\^)?\s?\d{4}'  #regex for checking if its a single year or period

#checking if a normal regex works
print re.search(r'W', list_elem, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print re.findall(r'W\w+', list_elem, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

#main regex
print re.search(period_regex, list_elem, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print re.findall(period_regex, list_elem, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

The Output is:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f8bfd1b5510>
['Whiting']
None
[]
```

The regex I've written seems to be working correct. Here's the link to regex: https://regex101.com/r/scAtgw/2

However, I still get an empty match when I run my program. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: Maybe it is related to the Unicode. Here, [it works](https://ideone.com/pl9CBp). BTW, I think you need to replace all capturing groups with non-capturing if you need to just get all matches. Like `r'(?:\d{1,2}\^)?\s?\d{4}\s?[–-]\s?(?:\d{1,2}\^)?\s?\d{4}'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, this is a much better regex and does what I want, but I still cannot get any matches on my machine. Any ideas how to fix the unicode related problem?

Comment: You need to make the `list_elem` a Unicode string by adding `u""` prefix to its declaration. See https://ideone.com/0d4nqv.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I did that, still no results :(

Comment: Look, it works here - https://ideone.com/Ltw4rA.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Okay, this will sound weird, but I wrote pretty much the same code as you did, and it wasn't working, but when I copy pasted it and restarted my terminal, it started to work. Anyway, it works now, much Thanks!!

Comment: I posted a full answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is that since you are working with a Unicode text, the input string should be Unicode, too. This can be fixed by adding a `u` prefix to the string literal.

However, there will be an issue with `re.findall` that only returns capturing group contents if they are defined in the pattern. And since your pattern contains capturing groups, you will get a list of tuples as a result. So, you need to convert all capturing groups into *non-capturing* ones.

And if you need to print the values, you might need to `.encode("utf8")` the values.

See the  [Python 2 demo online](https://ideone.com/Ltw4rA):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
list_elem = u'''Frank P. Smith (1886–1888)
    Edgar Grant Sisson (1914–1917)
    Douglas Z. Doty (1917–1918)
     {{Ray Long}} (1918–1931)

    Harry Payne Burton (1931–1942)
    Frances Whiting (1942–1945)
    Arthur Gordon (1946–1948)'''

period_regex = ur'(?:\d{1,2}\^)?\s?\d{4}\s?[–-]\s?(?:\d{1,2}\^)?\s?\d{4}'  #regex for checking if its a single year or period
print re.search(r'W', list_elem, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print re.findall(r'W\w+', list_elem, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

print re.search(period_regex, list_elem, flags=re.IGNORECASE).group(0).encode('utf8')
for x in  re.findall(period_regex, list_elem, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
    print x.encode('utf8')
```

Result:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x2b05baf525e0>
[u'Whiting']
1886–1888
1886–1888
1914–1917
1917–1918
1918–1931
1931–1942
1942–1945
1946–1948
```

Note the `u"""` in `list_elem = u'''Frank` and all `(` are replaced with `(?:` in the pattern making the groups non-capturing.

Also, `[–-]` is the same as `(?:–|-)` but is shorter and more efficient.

Comment: This is precisely the answer I was looking for. And thanks for improving the regex too :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding 'u' as prefix in `list_elem` and `.encode('utf8')` in the print statements should solve your problem. For example,

```
print re.search(period_regex, list_elem, flags=re.IGNORECASE).group(0).encode('utf8')
```